# koel - error when execute php artisan koel:init command

Tags: php, laravel, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run [Koel](https://github.com/phanan/koel) and run every command that needs to run the project.

I read the doc, part of the installation.

- The first step runs every command about getting and executes the project: https://github.com/phanan/koel

```sh
$ cd <PUBLIC_WEB_DIRECTORY_FOR_KOEL>
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/phanan/koel.git .
$ git checkout v4.0.0 # Check out the latest version at https://github.com/phanan/koel/releases
$ composer install
$ php artisan koel:init # Populate credentials during the process

$ php artisan serve
```

After execute `php artisan koel:init` command, I get the following error:

```
yarn install v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > eslint-config-vue@2.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning " > eslint-plugin-vue@2.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.2.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:289:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ramtin\\Desktop\\koel\\resources\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel\resources\assets\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Oops! Koel installation or upgrade didn't finish successfully.
Please try again, or visit https://koel.phanan.net/docs for manual installation.
 Sorry for this. You deserve better.
```

I read errors and search on the internet (GitHub and...) but I can't find anything.

Comment: What was the output of running `yarn install`? Is `@phanan/vuebus` listed in your `package.json` as a `dependency` or a `devDependency`?

Comment: no @phanan/vuebus doesn't listed on package.json! the output is warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.    
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.92s.

Comment: Is it in `package-lock.json`?

Comment: I searched but I can't be finding anything!

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your dependencies. That product's [installation instructions](https://koel.phanan.net/docs/#/?id=installation) don't say anything about running `yarn`. Are you sure you're following the right instructions?

Comment: yes, I'm sure ... and twice did it! :)

Comment: "and twice did it"… meaning you aren't having this problem anymore? If so, please delete your question.

Comment: if I didn't run yarn when run artisan serve and see web site on browser I faced this error: https://github.com/phanan/koel/issues/557 .

Comment: In `C:\Users\ramtin\Desktop\koel-master\koel\resources\assets\js\utils`. Try on Unix like machine - macOS, Debian.  Or even better docker
`because it works on my`

Comment: what should i do exactly?!

Comment: please check the question again(edited) and the question has changed.

Answer (score 0):

apparently in the master branch of [koel](https://github.com/koel/koel) assets are in a separate repo.
Cloning the repo recursively should fix it.

```
git clone https://github.com/koel/koel.git --recursive
```

if not work try this after:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```